# OpenSSH server frozen, can't unfreeze using Escape Char in OpenSSH client

Tags: ssh

Connecting to Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 from a OpenSSH client in Xubuntu 15.04

I can't unfreeze the session which has timed out, I have tried the ~. escape character but the terminal won't even let me type those. What am I doing wrong?

The output

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chosenu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chosenu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chosenu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chosenu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@192.168.0.5's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
user@192.168.0.5's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.0.5 ([192.168.0.5]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
```

Also my ssh_config already has the line:

```
EscapeChar ~
```

Another strange thing I have just noticed is that I can connect from ConnectBot on my Android and it seems to be working. Is there any way I could kill the ssh server from the ConnectBot session so that I can connect normally from my Xubuntu machine? I would still like to know how I could unfreeze the session if possible though, as I guess this may happen frequently.

The plot thickens: I tried to kill the sshd from Connectbot and then tried to reconnect, and it's still frozen?! I am really confused now.

Update: And now it works after I restarted the client machine. (maybe placebo or the service somehow restarted in-between). It would be nice if someone had an explanation but I guess I can live with kill the process if this happens again.

Answer (score 0):

The `~.` sequence only works if it's at the beginning of a line. Try hitting `return` first, then `~.`.

Comment: I tried that, but it wouldn't work. The command line was totally frozen for some reason, but it let me login. I have no idea what caused it, I haven't done much with ssh until now.

Comment: I haven't seen this in a while, but software flow control might still be in play, sometimes triggered by `Ctrl-S`. You could try `Ctrl-Q`, though it's a long shot that is the issue.

Comment: I reset the machine with Ubuntu server (updated the question) so I will have to wait and see if it recurs to try that. I did try `Ctrl-Z` as I read a few issues on the net and some suggested that.